# get totals by year when invoices exists in both years

Tags: mysql

So I'm looking to total invoices per customer where an invoice exists in both years. So I have

```
SELECT     Sum((tbl_invoice_details.quantity 
                - ifnull(tbl_invoice_details.quantity_returned, 0)
                ) * tbl_invoice_details.price) AS dollarsSold,
           tbl_customers.NAME,
           cust_ID AS customer_id,
           YEAR (tbl_invoice.invoice_date) AS invoiceYear
FROM       `tbl_invoice_details`
INNER JOIN `tbl_invoice` 
ON         `tbl_invoice_details`.`invoice_ID` = `tbl_invoice`.`invoice_ID`
INNER JOIN `tbl_customers` 
ON         `tbl_customers`.`customer_ID` = `tbl_invoice`.`cust_ID`
WHERE      MONTH (`invoice_date`) = '2'
AND        (YEAR (`invoice_date`) = '2017'
            OR
            YEAR (`invoice_date`) = '2016')
AND EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM   tbl_invoice
            WHERE  cust_ID = customer_id
            AND    MONTH (`invoice_date`) = '2'
            AND    YEAR (`invoice_date`) = '2016')
GROUP BY    MONTH (tbl_invoice.invoice_date),
            invoiceYear,
            `tbl_customers`.`name`,
            customer_id
ORDER BY name
```

So how do I restrict it to customers that have an invoice in Feb of both 2016 and 2017. I attempted it with the `EXISTS` but that is only halfway successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to ensure that both invoices exists, is using EXISTS twice, one for 2016 and other for 2017.

```
SELECT     Sum((tbl_invoice_details.quantity 
                - ifnull(tbl_invoice_details.quantity_returned, 0)
                ) * tbl_invoice_details.price) AS dollarsSold,
           tbl_customers.NAME,
           cust_ID AS customer_id,
           YEAR (tbl_invoice.invoice_date) AS invoiceYear
FROM       `tbl_invoice_details`
INNER JOIN `tbl_invoice` 
ON         `tbl_invoice_details`.`invoice_ID` = `tbl_invoice`.`invoice_ID`
INNER JOIN `tbl_customers` 
ON         `tbl_customers`.`customer_ID` = `tbl_invoice`.`cust_ID`
WHERE      MONTH (`invoice_date`) = '2'
AND        YEAR (`invoice_date`) IN ('2016', '2017')
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM   tbl_invoice
            WHERE  cust_ID = customer_id
            AND    MONTH (`invoice_date`) = '2'
            AND    YEAR (`invoice_date`) = '2016')
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM   tbl_invoice
            WHERE  cust_ID = customer_id
            AND    MONTH (`invoice_date`) = '2'
            AND    YEAR (`invoice_date`) = '2017')
GROUP BY    MONTH (tbl_invoice.invoice_date),
            invoiceYear,
            `tbl_customers`.`name`,
            customer_id
ORDER BY name;
```